# Unable to insert data from c# to mysql database

Tags: c#, mysql

I have this problem. I create 2 tables in MySql which are connected together with foreign key. I want to insert data in the tables from c#.

table persons
id - int, auto increment, primary key
first_name - varchar
last_name - varchar

table addresses
id - auto increment, primary key
city - varchar
steet_number - varchar
persons_id - foreign key

```
  string mySqlString = "server=localhost;uid=root;pwd=root;database=address_book;";
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(mySqlString);
    try
    {
        conn.Open();

        string insertPerson = "INSERT INTO persons(first_name, last_name) VALUES (@first_name, @last_name)";
        string insertAddress = "INSERT INTO addresses(city, street_number, persons_id) VALUES (@city, @street_number, @persons_id)";

        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(insertPerson, conn);
        MySqlCommand secondCommand = new MySqlCommand(insertAddress, conn);

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@first_name", TextBox1.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@last_name", TextBox2.Text);
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(command.LastInsertedId);

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        secondCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", TextBox3.Text);
        secondCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@street_number", TextBox4.Text);
        secondCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@persons_id", id);

        secondCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (MySqlException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Clone();
    }
```

But this is not working, how should I get the last inserted value from the primary key to insert that value in column "persons_id"? Or maybe I'm wrong somewhere else ?

Comment: Take a look: you are concatenating two sql statements without ';'. Instead of this, why you don't separate the two statements and execute it in a transaction?

Comment: I tried this, but this was not the problem. I can make two string and two command, but still get the error. The problem is I don't know how to get the last value from column "table.id".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one go you can use `LAST_INSERT_ID()` directly on the query:

```
string insertPerson = "INSERT INTO persons(first_name, last_name) VALUES (@first_name, @last_name);"
                    + "INSERT INTO addresses(city, street_number,persons_id) VALUES (@city, @street_number, LAST_INSERT_ID());";
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(insertPerson, conn);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@first_name", TextBox1.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@last_name", TextBox2.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", TextBox3.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@street_number", TextBox4.Text);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Alternatively you can run 2 commands 1 to insert the person and retrieve the ID and the other to insert the addresses:

```
string insertPerson = "INSERT INTO persons(first_name, last_name) VALUES (@first_name, @last_name)";
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(insertPerson, conn);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@first_name", TextBox1.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@last_name", TextBox2.Text);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
int id = Convert.ToInt32(command.LastInsertedId);
```

An alternative way would be using the double query like this:

```
string insertPerson = "INSERT INTO persons(first_name, last_name) VALUES (@first_name, @last_name); SELECT last_insert_id();";
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(insertPerson, conn);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@first_name", TextBox1.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@last_name", TextBox2.Text);
int id = Convert.ToInt32(comm.ExecuteScalar());
```

Then you can use the resulting `id` on your next query.

Comment: You should put both queries in single transaction scope.

Comment: 1st query == `one of your demonstrations`;  2nd query == `Then run your 2 query and use the id.`. You should run both 1st and 2nd within single transaction.

Comment: Correct you are not using it - but you are _telling_ OP to use it by saying `Then run your 2 query and use the id.`. Thus, it is important that both commands are run in same transaction - and that is my original suggestion.

Comment: @Prix I edit the code but, I'm now getting a new error.
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint falls

Comment: @PUDEV you're doing it wrong look at the example carefully you're placing `int id = Convert.ToInt32(command.LastInsertedId);` before the `command.ExecuteNonQuery();` it should be after, you can also use the first example on my answer it will handle both queries in one go.

Comment: @Prix now it's working after that, thank you, even separeted in two commands